# How to refactor some function inside a Protractor Page Object or spec file into a separate file?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

For PageObject, we have buttons/links in the bottom of the page. We have to scroll down to the bottom so as to click.

```
var ContactAddPage = function() {
    ...
    this.btnAdd = element(by.id('btnAdd'));

    this.add = function() {
        scrollToBottom();
        this.btnAdd.click();
    };

    function scrollToBottom(){
        browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,10000);');
    }
};
```

Since `scrollToBottom()` will be used in many other page object, I assume we could refactor it out into a separator file and somehow `require()` it into the page object. But how to do that?

---

As for the spec files, there would be common functions like log in with different persona in `beforeAll()` and log out in `afterAll()`. And checking url is also common to each page:

```
function loginAs(role) {
    var loginPage = new LoginPage();
    loginPage.login(role);
}

function logOut() {
    var lnkLogOff = element(by.linkText('Log off'));
    if (element(by.linkText('Log off')).isPresent()) lnkLogOff.click();
}

function expectRouteToBe(expectUrl) {
    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toBe(browser.baseUrl + expectUrl);
}
```

The same question here: what is the correct way to move them out and `require()` them back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend modules by using exports and prototype inheritances... then you can have methods available in any or all of your pages. Eg. something like:

basePage.js:

```
var BasePage = function() {
    this.loginAs = function(role) {
        this.login(role);
    };

    ...
};
module.exports = new BasePage();
```

And then extend any number of pages thusly:

```
var basePage = require('./basePage.js');

var MainPage = function() {
    this.btnAdd = element(by.id('btnAdd'));

    this.add = function() {
        this.scrollToBottom();
        this.btnAdd.click();
    };

    this.scrollToBottom = function() {
        browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,10000);');
    };
};
MainPage.prototype = basePage;
module.exports = new MainPage();
```

And then in your spec, you can:

```
var mainPage = require("../pages/mainPage.js");

...
it('should login and click add', function() {
    mainPage.loginAs(role);
    mainPage.btnAdd.click()
    ...
});
```

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 1):

We've had something similar in our set of protractor e2e tests. We've created a set of helper libraries for the reusable functionality used in tests.

Example:

- create `helpers.js` file:

  ```
  var Helpers = function() {
      this.scrollToBottom = function () {
          browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,10000);');
      };
  };

  module.exports = new Helpers();
  ```
- require and use it in your Page Object:

  ```
  var helpers = require("./helpers.js");

  var ContactAddPage = function() {
      this.btnAdd = element(by.id('btnAdd'));

      this.add = function() {
          helpers.scrollToBottom();
          this.btnAdd.click();
      };
  };

  module.exports = ContactAddPage;
  ```